# How to save data like database column on variable?

Tags: dart, flutter

How to save and read variable of 2 items?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start creating a class representing the "row" of your table:

```
class MyItem{
    int DefCatId;
    String Description;
}
```

and then store everything in a `List<MyItem>`.

**EDIT**

You can do this the following way:

```
List<MyItem> myList = List<MyItem>();
myList.add(myItem);
```

Where `myItem` (lowercase m) is an instance of `MyItem`.

Check [here](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/List-class.html) for info on how to use a Dart `List`.

Comment: I didn't use a Json. You can query your Database, then  map each row into `MyItem` and add them to the List

Comment: you can use the `add` method on the list, but there's also `addAll` and other stuff in the link I've provided. But `add`  should be just fine

Comment: I've added an example in the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
class Product {
  final int id;
  final String description;

  Product({this.id, this.description});
}

List<Product> products = [];

void writing() {
  Product product = Product(id: 4, description: "Access/Status");
  products.add(product);
}

void reading() {
  for (var product in products) {
    int id = product.id;
    String desc = product.description;
  }
}
```